# update statement is not working in sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
select eid, pid,
case when i_flag='Y' and i_deleted='Y' then 'Y' else 'N' end
from test_emp
where desig in ('it','hr','account')
group by eid, pid,
case when i_flag='Y' and i_deleted='Y' then 'Y' else 'N' end;
```

now i want to update the columns i_status to 'Y' when i_flag='Y' and i_deleted='Y' then 'Y' else 'N' end
from test_emp
where desig in ('it','hr','account')
group by eid, pid,
case when i_flag='Y' and i_deleted='Y' then 'Y' else 'N' end;

my update stmt is not working:-

```
update t1
set t1.i_status=t2.result
(case when i_flag='Y' and i_deleted='Y' then 'Y' else 'N' end; 
from test_emp t1 ,test_emp t2
inner join t on t1.eid=t2.eid
where t1.desig in ('it','hr','account')
group by t1.eid, t1.pid,
case when t1.i_flag='Y' and t1.i_deleted='Y' then 'Y' else 'N' end);
```

Comment: What happens? Do you have an error? No rows are updated ? Please clarify

Comment: your update query has several syntax and logical errors.. you first `case` statement ends with a semicolon wich interrupts your query and what comes after makes no sense.. Please be more clear and format properly your code.

Answer (score 0):

No idea what you are trying to do but this is my best guess. This is of course 100% untested since we have no tables or data to work with. I will suggest looking at this article before posting your next question. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

```
update e
set i_status = case when i_flag='Y' and i_deleted='Y' then 'Y' else 'N' end
from test_emp e
where desig in ('it','hr','account')
```

Comment: pls dont give suggestions, if u dont know understand better ignore.

Comment: Well then perhaps you could be troubled to post enough information so that others can help. Best of luck. I hope you figure out a solution.